# jsons:getString() exception

Tags: wso2, ballerina

I'm getting an exception which feels like it might be a defect.  I'm wondering if anyone else sees a problem with this.  Here is simplified but runnable service I am writing.

```
import ballerina.net.http;
import ballerina.lang.messages;
import ballerina.lang.jsons;
import ballerina.lang.system;
@http:BasePath("/weather")
service WeatherService {

        @http:GET
        @http:Path("/current")
        resource current(message m) {
        string url = "http://api.mesowest.net/v2/stations/nearesttime?stid=KBFI&within=60&vars=air_temp,wind_speed,wind_direction&obtimezone=local&token=demotoken";
        http:ClientConnector weatherConnector = create http:ClientConnector(url);
        message request = {};
        message jsonResponse = http:ClientConnector.get(weatherConnector, "", request);
        json jsonDocument = messages:getJsonPayload(jsonResponse);
        json timestamp;
        string timeString;
        try {
            timestamp  = jsons:getJson(jsonDocument, "$..PERIOD_OF_RECORD.end");
        }
            catch (exception e) {
                    system:println("Error getting timestamp");
        }
        messages:setJsonPayload(m, timestamp);
            reply m;
        }
}
```

When I run this in the debugger, the json variable 'timestamp' is assigned the appropriate value from the JSON excerpt below:

```
"STATION": [
        {
            "STATUS": "ACTIVE",
            "MNET_ID": "1",
            "PERIOD_OF_RECORD": {
                "start": "1969-12-31T16:00:00-0800",
                "end": "2017-02-27T19:40:00-0800"
            }
```

When I replace the line:

```
timestamp  = jsons:getJson(jsonDocument, "$..PERIOD_OF_RECORD.end");
```

with the line

```
timeString  = jsons:getString(jsonDocument, "$..PERIOD_OF_RECORD.end");
```

and stop and restart the service and test it, it throws an exception on the getString method. I haven't found a way to print an exception yet or get attributes of the exception in order to find why its failing. The console out is as follows.

```
Running weather2.bal service.
ballerina: deploying service(s) in '/Users/clarkm2/Projects/Ballerina/Weather/weather2.bal'
ballerina: started server connector http-9090
Error getting timestamp
```

An idea on this?  If this is a defect, do these get reported on the wso2.com JIRA site?

Thanks.

Comment: Hi MattC, Any defect you find in ballerina should be reported on https://github.com/ballerinalang/ballerina/issues.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this error is that, the element returned by `$..PERIOD_OF_RECORD.end` is not a string. It returns the following

```
    "PERIOD_OF_RECORD": {
        "end": "2017-02-27T21:00:00-0800",
        "start": "1969-12-31T16:00:00-0800"
    },
```

which cannot be converted to text. If you log the exception in the catch block you will be able to observe the following error.

```
Error getting timestamp : Failed to get string from json. Error while executing jsonpath: The element matching path: $..PERIOD_OF_RECORD.end is not a String.
```

To log the exception modify your code as :

```
catch (exception e) {
     system:println("Error getting timestamp : " + exceptions:getMessage(e));
}
```

with `import ballerina.lang.exceptions` import statement.

Comment: When I run this in the debugger, the JSONPath "$..PERIOD_OF_RECORD.end" returns the json array "["2017-03-01T07:20:00-0800"]"

Comment: Sorry.  I'm unable to edit that last comment.  Here's the rest....This is different from what you stated.  Still, you are correct that this is not a string. When I change it to  $..PERIOD_OF_RECORD.end[0] to get the first element of that array it returns an empty array which also causes an exception. If I take the json document and the jsonpath and use an online evaluator, such as jsonpath.com, I get different results than what Ballerina is producing.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the jsonpath as follow:

```
string timeString  = jsons:getString(j, "$.STATION[0].PERIOD_OF_RECORD.end");
```